# Need of 'Field Required' against 'Required Validation Rules'

Tags: validation-rule, required-field

Please let me know why 'required attribute' while creating field when we can do with Validation rules.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Because validation rule can also be used in multiple different cases like total Amount cannot be less then 500. It is your choice and some time it is condition (make required the textarea field)due to which we will use validation rule for required fields.

Also it is better approach if you can make a field required using just just a checkbox click in place of writing logic for this.

Also if you make this required using required attribute then you will get required UI using `inputfield` otherwise you need to handle this manually.

Also you cannot remove required field from UI created using required attribute but with the validation you don't have such limitations.

So these are some example and difference between the required attribute and validation rules.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a shortcut use case. You can write a validation rule for that case or just check the box.

Comment: A field would not appear in [Mobile Smart Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=smart_actions_overview.htm&language=en_US) if it was not a required field, and you instead used a validation rule to ensure the field wasn't blank.

Answer (score 0):

From a user experience perspective, it's better to use the Required attribute on the field -- which is reflected in the UI -- than a validation rule, which won't have a visual indicator of the rules. It's better for the user to see and know the field is required than to find out when you submit the form and get an error message.

Answer (score 0):

From the view point of making fields required we can notice this redundancy in functionality considering that the 'required' checkbox and validation rules exist at the same time while VR can easily take care of making a field required.

Seeing it from an empirical angle, the 'required' checkbox is more a part of the data model. It constricts the data model in such a way by making sure that these particular characteristics(fields) of the object must be filled to make this a meaningful instance of the object. A person object will have 'Age' and 'sex' fields and these need to be mandatory because these two values for a particular instance/person/record are part of the basic definition of that person. Hence we make this fields required at the field level.

Coming to validation rules, they represent the business logic part. They are more towards 'C' in MVC. They define conditions that need to be satisfied and it happens so that making a field required is one of the basic conditions that these VRs allow us to implement. It is just that the VRs are meant to implement wider logic to ensure data quality and adherence to real data. In the person object, we can write a validation rule such that if the person is below 18, the guardian's name should be compulsorily filled.

From a salesforce implementation perspective, the difference is when we make a field required at the field, then we tie the field metadata with that information. Now the whole system knows from the metadata that the field is required. This impacts behaviour from interacting components like(as other answers mentioned):

1. The FLS makes the field editable at all times
2. Field cannot be removed from layout
3. The field is marked inherently as required in VF pages

Summarising, 'required' at the field level is more of a data model constraint while VRs are regulations by business logic. In this case, different way of doing the same thing. Hope this helps.